# Find file name in content of other file

Tags: grep, find

There are many text file in folder.

I want to know which file's contain that mention to other file name in folder

example: Is name of file1 has mention in other file in folder1?

```
folder1
├── folder1.1/
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
└── folder1.2/
    ├── file3
    └── folder1.2.1/
        └── file4
```

Comment: Dear roaima. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` with `basename` to get the filenames, and then feed it to grep as patterns using `-f -`:

```
find . -type f -exec basename -a -- {} + | grep -Ff - -R .
```

Example:

```
$ tree
.
├── folder2
│   ├── f1
│   ├── folder2a
│   └── folder2b
│       └── f3
└── folder3
    ├── folder3a
    │   └── f2
    └── folder3b

6 directories, 3 files

$ find . -type f -exec basename -a -- {} + | grep -Ff- -R .
./folder2/folder2b/f3:f2
./folder3/folder3a/f2:f1
```